# Sharing Playstation Now with Vita

Tags: ps-vita, playstation-now

We have a PS4 and a couple of playstation network accounts.  My account has a PS Now subscription.  My son has a subaccount on our PS4 and he's able to play PS Now games on it.  He also has a Vita that is attached to his PSN account.  Can I share the family PS Now account with my son on his Vita?

Answer (score 0):

PlayStation Now can be shared on the PS4 because your account is the subscriber, and is on the same PS4 as your child's sub-account. However, on the PS Vita, only one user is supported and cannot be changed. As a result, your PlayStation Now subscription cannot be shared with the PS Vita, only the PS4.

The only way to get around this would be to sign-up to PlayStation Now on the sub-account, so you can access it on both the PS Vita and PS4. As your account will also be on the PS4, you'll be able to share the subscription.

**Note**: I've not tested this myself, but based on how the users work on both consoles and the sharing policies on the PS4, it should work in theory.

Comment: On a PS4 all subscriptions and games of the Primary User get shared will all other accounts on the machine. If they were to get the subscription on a sub-account they'd need to change primary user (if the family account is currently the primary user, which I assume it is). Another option would be to change the user on the Vita to the family account, though it wouldn't be his son's account. It all depends on how important the PS Now is on either account (is his son the only one that uses it) and is it important that his son plays on his own account on the Vita.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot. The only reason he can play it on the ps4 is because your account is set as home.  But the vita only supports one account at a time, so this alone will keep you from gamesharing with a vita.  Sony really messed up a fantastic lil handheld.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi David, did you read the other answer? This doesn't really add anything new to it.